# How to update a value in session storage getItem/setItem

Tags: javascript, protractor, session-storage

I am using protractor and need to access a session storage key and then update value for a specific key inside the returned object.

```
browser.driver.executeScript('return window.sessionStorage.getItem("claims_obj");').then((retVal) => {
            console.log(':::***:::' + retVal);
          });
```

It prints the following -

```
{
"code": "123"
"description": "desc"
"imageUrl": "TODO"
"firstName": "test"
"lastName": "test"
"name": "test test"
"roles": ["ADMIN USER READ WRITE"]
"userId": "654"
}
```

Even though it looks like a JSON object, but for some reason, it gives `typeof` as `string`
I need to update roles to `[READ]` but unable to do that. Any idea as how can we do it?

Comment: It's not a JSON object (there is no such thing), it's JSON. As in, text. To change it, you need to call `JSON.parse()` on it (which parses the text and returns an Object). A browser's sessionStorage/localStorage can only store strings.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me Chris. I am able to get the roles array now as per your suggestion. How can I empty roles array and push a new value to it?

Comment: `data.roles = ["NEW"];`?

Comment: `browser.driver.executeScript('return window.sessionStorage.getItem("claims_obj");').then((retVal: string) => {
            console.log(':::***:::' + JSON.parse(retVal).roles);
            JSON.parse(retVal).roles = ['READ'];
            console.log(':::***:::' + JSON.parse(retVal).roles);
          });` still prints the same roles array as in first line. What am I missing? It didn't update the roles array.

Comment: You keep creating a new object because you're calling `parse()` over and over again. You need `.then(retVal: string => { var data = JSON.parse(retVal); data.roles = ['READ']; console.log(data); });`

Comment: Thanks a bunch Chris, my bad. One last thing please - `browser.driver.executeScript('return window.sessionStorage.setItem("id_token_claims_obj", ' + data + ');').then((d) => {
                console.log('kkk' + d);
            });` returns unexpected identifier. I need to update the session storage.

Comment: replace `data` with `JSON.stringify(data)`. No guarantees though.

Comment: Okay, it goes away with `browser.driver.executeScript('return window.sessionStorage.setItem("id_token_claims_obj", ' + JSON.stringify(data) + ');').then((d) => {
                console.log('kkk' + d);
            });` but updates the session storage as object. earlier it was visible as JSON in dev tool.

Comment: Seems you need `'return window.sessionStorage.setItem("id_token_claims_obj", JSON.stringify(' + JSON.stringify(data) + '));'` (the inner one dumps the object into the script, the outers transform the object into a string inside the script context)

Comment: You are awesome Chris. I don't think I could have figured it out. Tons of thanks.

Comment: You're welcome, glad it's working :)